# HTTP Status 404?

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc

[image: Directory]

### AppConfig

```
package com.example.configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.SpringTest")
public class AppConfig {
         
     
    }
```

---

AppConfigInitialisation.java ##

```
    package com.example.configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
public class AppConfigInitialization  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
     @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
        }
      
        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }
      
        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/*" };
        }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.example.controller;
import com.example.model.*;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class UserController {
     @RequestMapping("/")
        public String welcome() {//Welcome page, non-rest
            return "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.";
        }
     
        @RequestMapping("/hello/{player}")
        public User user(@PathVariable String player) {//REST Endpoint.
     
            User msg = new User(player, "Hello " + player);
            return msg;
            
        }
            
}
```

---

### UserController.java

```
    package com.example.controller;
import com.example.model.*;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class UserController {
     @RequestMapping("/")
        public String welcome() {//Welcome page, non-rest
            return "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.";
        }
     
        @RequestMapping("/hello/{player}")
        public User user(@PathVariable String player) {//REST Endpoint.
     
            User msg = new User(player, "Hello " + player);
            return msg;
            
        }
            
}
```

---

### pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SpringTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    
    
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I getting "description The requested resource is not available.". i am trying to run it on tomcat v8.0 server. Even when i download the project spring projects from the sites and import them as a maven project , i get the same issue. Help me out

Comment: And the URL your request is?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/SpringTest

Comment: http://localhost:8000/SpringTest/Player/syam

Comment: Well, your request mapping says `/hello/{player}`. There's no `hello` in your URL.

Comment: but  
localhost:8000/SpringTest should show "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.". Not a single url is working

Comment: What happen if you access:  http://localhost:8000 ?

Comment: Does it compile? as you are using duplicate mapping in User and UserController classes. Any reason? @RequestMapping("/hello/{player}")

Comment: localhost:8000 it's says 404 . Resource not available . I even tried to change the location of tomcat but still same problem .

Comment: Sorry. . user is my pojo class . I wrote that by mistake . User class  have variables , parameterized constructor , setter and getter method

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add @RequestMapping("/") at the type level ( on top of UserController).

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the component scan base package as "com.example.SpringTest". But the UserController is in com.example.controller